# Present log in screen only if there are no data stored in user defaults

Tags: ios, session, userdefaults

I have an app which stores user data (mail and password) using UserDefaults. Once the user sends this information, next time he/she opens the app, the app should not show the registration view (as long as the user data is recorded).

I think this could be done with a Session but how can I tell the app to show the registration view only once (or when change in information is required)? An example of this could be the Facebook App: you have to log in, and when you open the App again everything is already loaded (main screen).

My app sends the information to a domain through PHP, so maybe a PHP session would help.

Comment: Just check the dictionary value of the key to see if it's not empty...

Comment: In my view ***Enabling State Preservation and Restoration in Your App*** would be a better option. Refer - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do the logic in app `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLauchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    guard let email = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "email"), let password = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "password") else {
        // Not set up yet
        showRegistration()
        return true
    }

    // Already signing up
    showLoginView()

    return true

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several types of Authentication specially when you are dealing with mobile apps and APIs then you are dealing with tokens.
This is how it usually goes on:

1. You send your **username & password** with your **clientSecret & clientId** that are created for your app by the API developer or owner to connect with it to the server. Example Code:

   ```
   func loginUser(email:String, pass:String, completion:@escaping (_ status:Bool, _ error:Error?, _ msg:String?) ->())
   {

   //Get Api keys from plist file then send login request
   helper.getApiKeys { (id, key) in

       let parameters = [

           "grant_type":"password",
           "client_id":id,
           "client_secret":key,
           "username":email,
           "password":pass,
           "scope":""

           ] as [String : Any]

       let header = [
           "Content-Type":"application/json"
       ]

       Alamofire.request(loginUserURL!, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header)
           .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
           .responseJSON { (response) in
               switch response.result {
               case .success( _):
                   let json = response.result.value!
                   let swiftyJson = JSON(json)
                   guard let expires = swiftyJson["expires_in"].double else {
                       return
                   }
                   let accessToken = swiftyJson["access_token"].stringValue
                   let refreshToken = swiftyJson["refresh_token"].stringValue
                   self.helper.setToken(expires: expires, aToken: accessToken, rToken: refreshToken)

                   completion(true, nil, nil)

               case .failure(let err):
                   //print(err)
                   if response.response?.statusCode == 401 {
                       completion(false,err,"Invalid Username or Password")
                   } else {
                       completion(false, err, "Error Logging In")
                   }
               }
       }

   }

   }
   ```
2. You receive in the closure function i built an **"access token"**, **"refresh token**" and an **"expiration time"**
3. You save the tokens and the expiration time using `UserDefaults` in your app and segue the user to the logged in page. Example code:

   ```
   //Save token in userdefaults
   func setToken(expires:Double, aToken:String, rToken:String) {

   //Change to expiry unix timeinterval date
   let expiryTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970 + expires

   let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
   userDefaults.set(expiryTime, forKey: "expires_in")
   userDefaults.set(aToken, forKey: "access_token")
   userDefaults.set(rToken, forKey: "refresh_token")
   }
   ```
4. Then in every time app comes to the foreground you check if the user is Authenticated. Which means that you will check if there is a token saved in the `UserDefaults` the expiration time of the token is still valid according to todays timestamp and if it is due to expiration you can refresh your token. Example code:

   ```
   //Get tokens
   private func getTokens (completion:(_ expires:TimeInterval?, _ accessToken:String?, _ refreshToken: String?) ->())
   {
   let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
   let access = userDefaults.string(forKey: "access_token")
   let refresh = userDefaults.string(forKey: "refresh_token")
   let expiry = userDefaults.double(forKey: "expires_in")

   if (access != nil && refresh != nil) {
       completion(expiry, access, refresh)
   } else {
       completion(nil,nil,nil)
   }
   }

   //Check if user is already Authenticated
   func isAuth() -> Bool {

   var status = false
   var apiId = Int()
   var apiKey = String()

   //Get tokens and test expiry time
   getTokens { (expiry, accessToken, refreshToken) in
       if (accessToken != nil && refreshToken != nil) {

           //If due to expiry then refresh
           if ((expiry! - Date().timeIntervalSince1970) < 2592000 /* 1 month */ ) {
               print(expiry!); print(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
               getApiKeys(completion: { (id, key) in
                   apiId = id
                   apiKey = key
               })
               refresh(refreshToken: refreshToken!, grantType: "refresh_token", clientId: apiId, clientSecret: apiKey, scope: "", completion: { (stat, err, msg) in

                   if stat {
                       status = true
                   } else {
                       status = false
                   }
               })

           } else {
               status = true
           }

       } else {
           status = false
       }
   }

   if status {
       return true
   } else {
       return false
   }
   }
   ```
5. So this means that the user is always logged in and will never be sent to the login viewController except if `isAuth()` function returns false. In my case passed the expiry date or the user has just logged out and i deleted his tokens. Example code:

   ```
   //Delete token for loggin out
   func logOut() {

   let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
   userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: "expires_in")
   userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: "access_token")

    // Segue user to login page

   }
   ```